# Print function returns two values

Tags: python

I have a created a function to print out the statistics of a tokenized text:

```
def print_statistics(text):
    print("\nThe total number of tokens is " +str(number_of_tokens(ny))+".")
    return ???
```

This function gives me two outputs (the second is "none"). But I want the function to give me the print output. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Do you want the string or the length?

Comment: Your question has zilch to do with NLP _or_ NLTK. In future, please refrain from adding tags that have nothing to do with your question. Tag spamming is against site guidelines.

Comment: That function does not give you any outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function could return the string to print:

```
def get_statistics_string(text):
    return "\nThe total number of tokens is " + str(number_of_tokens(ny)) + "."
```

Or print the statistics:

```
def print_statistics(text):
    print("\nThe total number of tokens is " + str(number_of_tokens(ny)) + ".")
    # note that it will still return None)
```

It is usually a good idea to decide that a function will either do something, or return something, not both.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the function to `print` the required output, then do the following:

```
def print_statistics(text):
    print("\nThe total number of tokens is " +str(number_of_tokens(ny))+".")
    return
```

Else if you want your function to `return` the required output, do the following:

```
def print_statistics(text):
    return "\nThe total number of tokens is " +str(number_of_tokens(ny))+"."
```

Answer (score 1):

> This function gives me two outputs (the second is "none").

You are executing the function in your Python shell (the builtin one, IPython or whatever). The Python shell always display the result of the last expression you eval'd. Since your function doesn't explicitely returns anything, it (implicitely) returns `None`, which is your "second output" - the first "output" being the function printing to `sys.stdout`. If you execute this function from a script, you will only see what the function prints.

What you mean by "I want the function to give me the print output" is quite unclear. If you want your function to print to `sys.stdout` then it's done, you have nothing to change. If you want it to instead return the formatted string (the one it currently prints) as a Python variable, then replace `print('yourstringhere')` by `return 'yourstringhere'`.

As a side note: learn to use proper string formatting, it's much easier to read and maintain:

```
nb_tokens = number_of_tokens(ny)
msg = "\nThe total number of tokens is {}.".format(nb_tokens) 
# then either `print(msg)` or `return msg`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just have the function return the output, like:

```
def print_statistics(text):
    return "\nThe total number of tokens is " +str(number_of_tokens(ny))+"."
```

Comment: You want to repeat the same thing that 2 other answers have said?